# WFS Insert transaction through geoserver cannot find declarations for schema elements

Tags: geoserver, wfs, wfs-t

I am attempting to post the following xml through geoserver to make a WFS insert:

```
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" service="WFS" version="2.0.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:my_db="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/my_db" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/my_db http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typename=test_db:avoidance_points" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <wfs:Insert>
    <my_db:avoidance_points>
      <my_db:weight>2</my_db:weight>
    </my_db:avoidance_points>
  </wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

The schema at the specified url ([...]/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?[...]) is as follows, and the relevant store is backed by a postgis database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:test_db="test_db" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="test_db">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://192.168.1.19:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="avoidance_pointsType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="geom" nillable="true" type="gml:PointPropertyType"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="distance" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="weight" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="avoidance_points" substitutionGroup="gml:AbstractFeature" type="test_db:avoidance_pointsType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

This results in no insertions.  I am aware that, as I'm attempting to simplify the problem as much as possible for debugging, I am not specifying all values within the schema (geom, distance), but neither of these are set to 'not null', so I don't expect that this is my underlying issue.

After putting geoserver into verbose logging, the following appears in the log:

```
2022-02-19 04:13:53,885 DEBUG [geoserver.requests] - First 4 bytes of XML doc are : 3C ('<') 3F ('?') 78 ('x') 6D ('m')
2022-02-19 04:13:53,885 DEBUG [geoserver.requests] - Charset detection phase 1. Inferred encoding: UTF-8
2022-02-19 04:13:53,885 DEBUG [geoserver.requests] - Charset detection phase 2. Charset in XML declaration is `null`.
2022-02-19 04:13:53,885 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Raw XML request: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" service="WFS" version="2.0.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:my_db="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/my_db" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/my_db http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typename=test_db:avoidance_points" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <wfs:Insert>
    <my_db:avoidance_points>
      <my_db:weight>2</my_db:weight>
    </my_db:avoidance_points>
  </wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>
2022-02-19 04:13:53,886 INFO [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getServiceInfo
2022-02-19 04:13:53,887 DEBUG [xsd.impl] - schemaLocation found: http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/my_db http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typename=test_db:avoidance_points
2022-02-19 04:13:53,888 DEBUG [xsd.impl] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0: http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/home/pjablonski/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-26.2.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v2_0/wfs.xsd
2022-02-19 04:13:53,889 DEBUG [xsd.impl] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2: http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd ==> jar:file:/home/pjablonski/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-gml3-26.2.jar!/org/geotools/gml3/v3_2/gml.xsd
2022-02-19 04:13:53,889 DEBUG [wfs.xml] - Hostname localhost is in known aliases for self
2022-02-19 04:13:53,895 DEBUG [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/my_db}avoidance_points. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
2022-02-19 04:13:53,895 DEBUG [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/my_db}avoidance_points. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
2022-02-19 04:13:53,895 DEBUG [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/my_db}avoidance_points. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
2022-02-19 04:13:53,896 DEBUG [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/my_db}weight. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
2022-02-19 04:13:53,896 DEBUG [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/my_db}weight. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
2022-02-19 04:13:53,896 DEBUG [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: {http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/my_db}weight. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
2022-02-19 04:13:53,897 DEBUG [geoserver.wfs] - Insert was empty - does not need a FeatureSource
2022-02-19 04:13:53,897 INFO [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: transaction
    service = WFS
    version = 2.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    group[0] = wfs:abstractTransactionAction=net.opengis.wfs20.impl.InsertTypeImpl@411828cc (handle: null) (any: [], inputFormat: <unset>, srsName: null)
    abstractTransactionActionGroup[0] = wfs:abstractTransactionAction=net.opengis.wfs20.impl.InsertTypeImpl@411828cc (handle: null) (any: [], inputFormat: <unset>, srsName: null)
    abstractTransactionAction[0]:
        inputFormat = application/gml+xml; version=3.2
    releaseAction = ALL
2022-02-19 04:13:53,899 DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: text/xml
2022-02-19 04:13:53,899 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2022-02-19 04:13:57,877 TRACE [platform.resource] - polling contents of /home/pjablonski/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
2022-02-19 04:13:57,877 TRACE [platform.resource] - delta computed in 319us for /home/pjablonski/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
```

My interpretation of this is that somehow, geoserver is failing to load my my_db namespace.  How can I fix this?

Comment: which version of GeoServer are you using?

Comment: @IanTurton I'm on 2.20.2, with geotools 26.2, geowebcache 1.20.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your features are in the `test_db` namespace not the `my_db` which is why the lookup of the schema fails.

See:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
  xmlns:test_db="test_db" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"                        elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="test_db">
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I'm not entirely sure why.  I would have expected that by manually specifying it in schemaLocations it would have made itself work.

At the same time, I'm now having the issue that it's complaining about "Source was null in trying to create a reprojected feature collection", which is strange since I'm not even including any geometries yet.  Odd!

Comment: Your way would be ok iff the describeFeatureType response returned a schema for `my_db` but it doesn't - at least I think that's the problem